# Why does indexof fail for arrays converted to lists in java?

Tags: java, arrays, casting, boolean, indexof

Let's say I have a boolean array that I want to find the first "true" entry in.
Since Java array don't have an indexOf-method, I thought of doing it this way:

```
boolean[] bArr = new boolean[]{true, true, true, true, true};
int index = Arrays.asList(bArr).indexOf(true);
```

Now why does this result in the index' being -1 (i.e. "no true found").

compilable: http://ideone.com/DdNoVw

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because `Arrays.asList(bArr)` is creating a `List<boolean[]>` not a `List<Boolean>`. `Arrays.asList` does not box your `boolean[]` array to a `Boolean[]` array (note the difference).

Hence you only have a List with a single boolean array at index 0.

If you used `Boolean[] bArr = new Boolean[]{true, true, true, true, true};`, `index` would have the value 0.

So the ways to overcome this problem is:

- create an empty List, loop through your array and add each item to the list (each boolean will be boxed to Boolean)
- write a simple utility method that takes a `boolean[]` array as parameter and the value to be found